# How do I find my object using the package function I created?

Tags: r, function, package

My vignette for a package I created does not work because of the following error:

```
    Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'data.begEndGrp' not found
```

I believe it has something to do with my function `gardaltplot` being masked by the global environment. Code is below:

## Function

```
    gardaltplot <- function(tbl, x, y, aname, bname) {
      # Performing unpaired (two independent groups) analysis.
      unpaired_mean_diff <- dabestr::dabest(tbl, x, y,
                                  idx = c("aname", "bname"),
                                  paired = FALSE)

      # Create a Gardner-Altman estimation plot.
      p<-dabestr::plot(unpaired_mean_diff)

      return(gaplot)
    }
```

## Vignette

````
    ```{r gardaltplot}
    library(estplot)
    data("BCdataMeasure")
    gardaltplot(BCdataMeasure, begEndGrp, sumPedBCByYr, "beginning", "ending")
    ```
````

My expected output is a plot. If I run the program, not as a 
       function inside a package, the result is the plot that I want.

Comment: can you share your data? Your function shouldn't be masked by the global environment unless you have an object with the same name in the global

Comment: Is your package `estplot`? Make sure you load your package in the vignette.

Comment: The error message makes it sound like the problem is with the `data.begEndGrp`. Can you show the  line of code that uses that name? Your function uses `begEndGrp`, not `data.begEndGrp`...

Comment: Sorry, the error was "begEndGrp" not "data.begEndGrp". I was trying different things out to see if any worked.

Comment: Yes, 'estplot' is the package. I added a line, 'install.packages("estplot")' and got the same error.